# Newtonsoft PopulateObject - Value Cannot be Null Exception

Tags: c#, json.net, populate

I am trying to populate an existing instance of a custom enumerable that contains objects that include `enum` properties.  When I do, I am getting an error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null` from `JsonConvert.PopulateObject()`.  What can be causing this?  Here is my sample:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CLYN3L

I am trying to see whether any of the following below are reasons:

1. having enums in my class.
2. my class inherits `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable`.

I have below classes and enums which I do not have control. I cannot change them:

```
public enum ErrorDisplayType : int 
{
    PopUp = 0,
    ErrorPane = 1,
    Statusbar = 2
}

[Serializable()]
public class ErrorObj 
{
   private string errorCode;
   private ErrorDisplayType errorDispType;

   public string ErrorCode 
   {
     get { return this.errorCode; }
     set {
        this.errorCode = value;
        if (errorCode != null)
        {
           this.setFields(errorCode);
        }
     }
   }
   public ErrorDisplayType ErrorDispType 
   {
      get { return this.errorDispType; }
      set { this.errorDispType = value; }
   }

    private void setFields(string errorCode) 
    {
       this.errorDispType = (ErrorDisplayType)int.Parse(errorCode);
    }   
}

[Serializable]
public class ErrorDTO : IEnumerator, IEnumerable 
{
   private int indx = -1;
   private List<ErrorObj> errorList;

   public List<ErrorObj> ErrorList 
   {
     get { return this.errorList; }
     set { this.errorList = value; }
   }

   public ErrorDTO()
   {
        this.errorList = new List<ErrorObj>();
   }

   public int Add(ErrorObj error)
   {
    this.errorList.Add(error);
    return 0;  
   }

   public bool MoveNext()
   {
      if (indx < errorList.Count - 1)      
      {                                    
         ++indx;                          
         return true;                     
      }                                    
      else                                 
      {                                    
         indx = -1;                       
         return false;                    
      }                                    
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
      this.indx = -1;
    }

    public object Current                                                            
    {                                                                               
       get                                                                          
       {                                                                            
         if (errorList.Count == 0 || indx < 0 || indx > errorList.Count - 1)
         { 
            return null;                                                         
         }
         return this.errorList[indx];                                             
       }                                                                            
    } 
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()  
    {
      return (IEnumerator)this;
    }

}
```

I have method ( which I cannot change ) which gives me JSON string like below

```
[{
    "ErrorCode": "ABCD125",
    "ErrorDispType": 1
}]
```

Which I generate as follows:

```
// below is already existing code
private static ErrorObj CreateErrorObj(string errorCode)
{
   ErrorObj error = new ErrorObj();
   error.ErrorCode = "ABCD125";
   error.ErrorDispType = (ErrorDisplayType)int.Parse(errorCode);
   return error;    
}

public string GetErrorJSON()
{
  ErrorDTO errDTO = new ErrorDTO();
  ErrorObj errObj = CreateErrorObj("1");
  errDTO.Add(errObj);

  string returnValue = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errDTO);
  return returnValue;
 }
```

Below is my code and I am trying to deserialize

```
ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO();
string jsonString = GetErrorJSON();
```

Below line throws me error. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, errorDTO);
```

Please let me know what is the problem. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @dbc... I edited my post.. at this line.. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, errorDTO);.. I get Value cannot be null exception

Comment: The fact that `ErrorDTO` is its own enumerator goes against .Net best practices, for it means that `ErrorDTO` cannot be iterated more than once at the same time.  I don't think this is causing this specific bug, but it probably will eventually cause some sort of bug.  Are you sure this cannot be changed?

Comment: `private List<ErrorObj> errorList;`  This is not initialized.  Try `private List<ErrorObj> errorList = new List<ErrorObj>();`

Comment: @dbc... I commented setFields(value) method... getting exception... please see this.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/dsJCIt   …. if you still feel wrong.. let me know I will delete this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you have declared `ErrorDTO` as `IEnumerator, IEnumerable`, which is to say an untyped, non-generic enumerable.  Json.NET interprets such an object as a **read-only untyped collection**, so when you try to to populate it, you get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   at System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.PopulateInternal(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(String value, Object target, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(String value, Object target)
```

The exception message is non-useful and misleading, but the real cause is that Json.NET has no way to know either the target type of the collection's items to which to deserialize, or the method to add them once deserialized, for any untyped, read-only collection.

The normal way to solve such a problem would be to declare `ErrorDTO` as an `ICollection<ErrorObj>` and implement the necessary generic methods, thereby informing Json.NET of both the item type and the [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, but unfortunately you state

> I cannot change them [the classes].

Thus the simplest workaround would be to populate the underlying list:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, resultDTO.ErrorList);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7FIF8).

Comment: Wow what an explanation.. This solved my issue and understand it.... Thank you very much....I also felt my class declared as IEnumerator might be issue....